# While MVC is rendering the View - Can you tell it to stop rendering at a certain point?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, rendering

I am trying to see if there is a MVC functionality that can stop rendering the page at a certain point.I know you can structure it any way you want to accomplish the task

```
@If SomeCondition = True THen 
 HTML CODE RENDER ALL YOU WANT
ElseIf SomeCondition = False Then
 Do Nothing
End IF
```

but is there a StopRendering functionality that is exposed to us that we can use?

Sort of how you can `Exit For` from for loop may be?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, surprisingly trivial:

```
@if {somecondition)
{
    <p>HTML to render</p>
}
```

If somecondition is false then the HTML won't get rendered.  Just put the rest of the html on your page within the @if condition and no other html will get rendered.